# regexp in oozie distcp action

Tags: hadoop, oozie, distcp

I am trying to copy all files that fit certain criteria into a folder

```
  <action name="copy_mta_c">
    <distcp xmlns="uri:oozie:distcp-action:0.2">
      <arg>${NAME_NODE}${PATH_COMVERSE}${CURRENT_DATE_NO_DASH}_*/*mta.gz</arg>
      <arg>${NAME_NODE}${PATH_MTA}/</arg>
    </distcp>
    <ok to="copy_mta_y"/>
    <error to="KILL"/>
  </action>
```

Here symbol `*` in `${CURRENT_DATE_NO_DASH}_*` stands for A or B or C etc. It searches for all folders. If I use `${CURRENT_DATE_NO_DASH}_A` it will only search 1 filder. How can I make it take only 2 out of all folders? I tried doing `(A|B)`, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this will be a `bash` expansion since your variables look like `bash` variables.

You can use this:

```
${CURRENT_DATE_NO_DASH}_[A-C]
```

Or this:

```
${CURRENT_DATE_NO_DASH}_{A,B,C}
```